# how to git log with date-time and file names in one line

Tags: git, git-log

I would like to have an git log (or in any other way) output like this,

```
2015-01-14 10:33:14 main.cpp
2014-10-30 11:30:22 some.cpp
2014-10-27 10:15:43 another.cpp
2014-10-27 09:41:22 main.cpp
2014-10-24 19:15:08 some.cpp
```

Basically the output should contain date, time and the file changed. And one entry should be in one line as example shows. 
I have checked pretty formats, but could not find a way to output the file names.

So, how to get something like this from git commands?

Comment: Now before posting - I know you looked at this http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log correct?

Comment: @Nefarii, yes I spent lot of time with different options in there :( I was able to get list of changed file in one instance and timestamps in another instance, but could not get both

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what awk's for.

```
git log --pretty=%x0a%ci --name-only \
| awk '
     /^$/        { dateline=!dateline; next }
     dateline    { date=$0; next }
     !seen[$0]++ { print date,$0 }
'
```

Comment: Great ! But how I can add some meta infos like "--stat" after the filename?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
git diff --name-only
```

that will get you changed filenames since your last commit

You can do

```
git diff --name-only <commit1> <commit2>
```

to get changed files between two commits

Comment: No. This will only generate list of files. I want their modification date and time as well.

Comment: yeh, sorry, actually, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28068704/5398655) should help you.