# Git: Fetch only files commited in particular commit, but not latest versions of all files

Tags: git

So I'm on my local machine and I have url to remote git repo.
What I need is to fetch from there to my local machine only files which were committed in the last commit. I.e. if only a.txt and b.txt were committed last time, I want to fetch only those two files and nothing else.

I know it sounds like a bit weird use case. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. The last commit is just a delta from the one before that. You need the entire history to get the actual file itself.

Comment: Once you have the history, you can look through it with the tools git provides and figure out which files were changed. Then you can delete everything else from the working dir or do whatever else you want with that information.

Comment: That's understandable. But how to limit all that repo history just to those files changed in the last commit. Kinda pretend that repo contains only a.txt and b.txt, and simply clone that repo than?

Comment: You can't. You'd have to clone the entire thing and then do something like `git filter-branch` to rewrite the history to get rid of everything but those two files, or just delete everything from the working directory that isn't them.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use `scp` or whatever remote copy tool you prefer to fetch the files from the server's working directory, if there is one.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks like grabbing everything and doing local filtering is the only way to go for me.

Comment: For now that seems like the best way. The machinery of git does not prevent something like this, there is just no script to do it that I am aware of for doing this in one step.

Comment: That being said, here's an idea: create a branch on the first commit (with no files in it), then merge a.txt and b.txt from the master branch. You could find out what a.txt and b.txt actually are from something like `git diff --name-only HEAD~ HEAD` (ripped from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5096268/2988730)).

Answer (score 0):

first pull the branch

```
git pull --rebase <repo> <branch>
```

then reset specific commits you don't want, and remaining you would get there.

`git reset --hard <commit-hash>`

also if you want to get hash use for particular commit

```
git log
```

edit :

You have to get the whole repo, but when you merge it locally, it only brings in the changed files.

The important line is this: (this sets your upper level branch, so it fetches from that only if base is updated )

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/original/repo.git
```

And then the actual fetching/merging can be done like this (two steps):

```
git fetch upstream master
git merge upstream/master
```

or in one step:

```
git pull upstream master
```

**Another way is to use SourceTree** : when you fetch the code, it will show you all uncommitted files, you can keep whatever you want. But, basically it will only show changed files which you want, and it does that.

Comment: How will this get you the last modifications for the files only in the last commit?

Comment: its one of the possible solution, if you believe its not possible, doesn't mean there's no way around..

Comment: OP wants specific files, not specific commits. Your solution does not address OP's question very well.

Comment: Removed my downvote because you gave me an idea, not because I think your suggestion helps much the way it is.

Comment: i don't care you do or not :D haha.. i answer and share what i know, if not him, this might be helpful to others