# Git how to track modified files in master branch

Tags: git

I am having two branches master and develop. I wanted to track all modified files and get their names before merging master with devlop branch. I have tried all solutions in these link - [How to get a list of all files that changed between two Git commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096268/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-that-changed-between-two-git-commits). I am only getting the modified files, when i am in develop branch before committing. One more option can be getting modified file name after pushing to develop branch. Any solutions for this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your is question is not understable. Please update it in order to allow us to help you.

Comment: I think OP is asking to get a *diff* of the two branches independent on what branch they currently are. What about `git diff --name-only branch1 branch2` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can run

```
git diff master --name-only
```

from your feature/development branch to see the modified files respect to master branch.
in general, you can specify one single commit id to have difference respect where you are, or two commit id to compare these.
Any strategy to specify a commit id will work, so for example you can do

```
git diff HEAD^^ --name-only
```

to see how many file you modified since two commits ago, or

```
git diff 0ccecd 1457aab --name-only
```

to see file difference between two commit you know by jhash.

Answer (score 0):

You should try diff, as explained in another answer but using `...` so that you can see what went on on one branch only. If you do not use the 3 dots, you get a plain diff between both branches which could potentially list files changed on either branch, not on just one of them

```
git diff --name-status master...develop
```

Comment: What's with all the typos? It looks like your keyboard went crazy :-)

Comment: hahaha Hadn't noticed.... and I was typing on the phone and probably had some salty food and my thumb is wider than usual XD. Thanks for bringing it up.